# Looping thru subdirectories

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, subdirectory

This is a section of code to expand .msu files that are in a few different subdirectories under the directory Updates.  The code below works but just in 1 subdirectory called General.  However there are 2 other subdirectories under this directory that it don't loop thru.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
FOR /R "%DestUpdatePath%\" %%n IN ("Windows%WinMSUVer%*%OSArch%*.msu") DO (
  SET msuDrive=%%~dn
  SET msuPath=%%~pn
  SET msuName=%%~nn
  SET msuPath=!msuPath:Updates=Processed!
  SET NewPath=!msuDrive!!msuPath!

IF NOT EXIST "!NewPath!!msuName!" MD "!NewPath!!msuName!"
EXPAND -F:* "%%n" "!NewPath!!msuName!"
)
```

Comment: To use `!msuDrive!!msuPath!` you must enable delayed expansion. See `setlocal /?`
.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir *.* /b /s') do @echo Drive %dA Path %~pA Name %~nA Extension %~xA`

Comment: Thanks Noodles. SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion is on, just not shown in this excerpt.  The script works but only processes one of the three sub directories.  I thought the /R meant walks the directory tree.  Why does it not process the other 2 sub directories?

Comment: Hey, got it figured out.  Not a problem with code, some msu files had unconventional filenames.  Thanks

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir c:\*.msu c:\*.msp /b /s') do @echo MD %~dpA%~nA & echo EXPAND -F:* "%A" "%~dpA%~nA"` is how to scan for two extensions. Note there are two echo commands. That;s your code on one line. Above is designed to be pasted, use %%A in a batch file.